# Why does this pointer to function work without warnings or errors?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Knowing that this call:

```
pow(4);
```

will generate this error message:

```
 error: too few arguments to function ‘pow’
```

I am learning pointers to functions and I got surprised when seen this code below working. But why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void aux(double (*function)(), double n, double x);

int main(void)
{
    aux(pow, 4, 2); 

    aux(sqrt, 4, 0);

    return 0;
}

void aux(double (*function)(double), double n, double x)
{   
    if(x == 0)
        printf("\nsqrt(%.2f, %.2f): %f\n", n, x, (*function)(n));  
    else
        printf("\npow(%.2f, %.2f): %f\n", n, x, (*function)(n));  
}
```

I compiled using:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -o test test.c -lm
```

The result is:

```
pow(4.00, 2.00): 16.000000

sqrt(4.00, 0.00): 2.000000
```

If I change the third parameter of the first call of `aux` to 3, the result changes to:

```
pow(4.00, 3.00): 64.000000

sqrt(4.00, 0.00): 2.000000
```

And one more question. What is the correct way to declare and use pointers to functions in this case?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That's not the problem. A missing `-lm` would cause a linker error.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right sir. My bad.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No need to apologize. Just delete the incorrect and distracting comments and go on.

Comment: i think that its has to do with how assembly work, the variable x is held into a register for example %ebx and you call the **fuction** with one argument but in reality its use 2 arguments, so its suppose that the second argument is in %ebx. // i'm not sure

Comment: @karim This has nothing to do with the machine-level. He's asking why the C compiler allows it.

Comment: He also asked why the code is working. He is not passing value of x to pow, and still getting correct results.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This:

```
void aux(double (*function)(), double n, double x);
```

uses an old-style non-prototype declaration for `function`. The empty parentheses `()` mean that the function takes a fixed but unspecified number and type(s) of arguments.

C still permits this kind of declaration for backward compatibility. Prototypes (function declarations that specify the types of the parameters) were introduced by ANSI C in 1989. Prior to that, it was not possible to specify parameter types in a function declaration, and compilers could not check whether a call passed the correct number and type(s) of arguments.

Such declarations are "obsolescent", meaning that support for them could be removed from a future C standard (but in more than 20 years the committee hasn't gotten around to removing them). Calling a function with the wrong number of types of arguments will not necessarily be diagnosed by the compiler, and the behavior is undefined.

The rules for *compatibility* of function types are a bit complicated when one has a prototype and the other doesn't. These types:

```
double(double)         /* function with one double parameter
                          returning double */
double(double, double) /* function with two double parameters
                          returning double */
```

are not compatible with each other, but they're *both* compatible with this type:

```
double()   /* function with a fixed but unspecified number of parameters
              returning double */
```

which is what makes it possible to have incorrect calls without a diagnostic from the compiler.

To avoid this problem, *always use prototypes*:

```
void aux(double (*function)(double, double), double n, double x);
```

Not only do you get better diagnostics from your compiler, you don't have to worry about the convoluted compatibility rules for non-prototyped functions (which, if you're curious, are specified in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.6.3 paragraph 16).

Comment: Still wondering how only one argument results in `pow` or `sqrt` calculation?

Comment: @haccks: Undefined behavior.

Comment: @haccks: You can wonder forever.  The behavior is **undefined**.  In principle, it might change the next time you run your program.  You cannot predict it, and you can only explain it by disassembling the binary to examine the code the compiler actually generated.  You cannot assume that the compiler will generate the same code the next time it compiles your program.

Comment: @AntoineMathys, you seem to have a problem with the concept of **undefined behavior**.  There is no meaningful explanation to be given based on the C language, and none at all available to anyone answering the question.

Comment: @AntoineMathys, Keith discusses the meaning of the given prototype, and writes: "Calling a function with the wrong number [or] types of arguments will not necessarily be diagnosed by the compiler, and the behavior is undefined," and "To avoid this problem, always use prototypes: [example elided]".  I don't know what more you want.

Comment: @AntoineMathys What problem should it catch? *You* told it to expect a function with varying number of parameters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I added the reference to undefined behavior just a few minutes ago.

Comment: @black: No, a function with a variable number of parameters (like `printf`) is declared with the `, ...` syntax. Empty parentheses mean a fixed but unspecified number of parameters.

Comment: I knew that it will invoke UB but was not sure. @JohnBollinger.

Comment: Compilers should be able to warn about this, but the `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` switch for gcc does not seem to catch this kind of bug. Do you know how to tell gcc/clang to complain about this?

Comment: @cmaster: I think it's `-Wmissing-prototypes` that induces GCC to emit such warnings.  I know it can do it, as I've had to sort through mountains of such warnings when working with legacy code.

Comment: "Empty parentheses mean a fixed but unspecified number of parameters".  Hmm I am certain `()` means the same as `(...)`.  IOWs no info about the number of parameters.

Comment: @chux: You may be certain, but I'm afraid you're mistaken. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.6.3 paragraph 16. `int printf();` is not compatible with `int printf(const char *format, ...);`. gcc says "a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration". BTW, `(...)` without at least one explicit parameter is illegal; the last named parameter is needed for `va_start()`.

Comment: Did not find `int printf(const char *format, ...);` in  N1570  §6.7.6.3 16.  In 14: "The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.1"  So re-stating:  `()` means the same as "no info about the number of parameters".  The number of parameters may be fixed or variable.  Code could declare a function with `int foo();` and define with  `int foo(int a, ...);`.

Comment: Yes, my equating `()` with `(...)` was off.  BTW `(...)` was legal in the early wild-west days - might have been pre-standard days.

Comment: @chux: Could be -- but to the best of my knowledge the `, ...` syntax was introduced by the 1989 ANSI C standard, which required at least one explicit parameter; without that, `va_start()` can't work. Might have been in some draft prior to the published standard. As for `(, ...)` vs. `()`, 6.7.6.3 paragraph 15 discusses compatibility, implies that `int printf(const char *format, ...);` and `int printf();` are incompatible. That does seem to contradict the "no information" wording in paragraph 14, but p15 is more specific. gcc agrees with me (which could mean gcc and I are both wrong).

Comment: The pre C89 `va_start()` worked with `va_start(...)`, but it was not called `va_start`.  IAC, that was long ago and having a function like `foo(...)` was not that useful.  IMO, p14 "no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied" preempts p15 isssues.  GCC could simple be more restrictive.  At the end-of-the day,  having a lesser function declaration with a more complete function definition may be legal, but I prefer them the same.

Comment: @chux: The legacy version was `<varargs.h>`. Its `va_start()` macro didn't require a named parameter, and always started with the very first parameter. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/varargs.h.html. As for `(...)` vs. `()`, I think we can agree that avoiding the obsolescent `()` form is a good idea.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I tried `-Wmissing-prototypes`, however, it does not complain about the underspecified function pointer argument :-( Of course, it complains about all the normal functions that are compiled without their prototype, which will catch 99% of the real world cases, but it's not 100%.

Answer (score 9):

Your prototype for function `aux()`...

```
void aux(double (*function)(), double n, double x);
```

... specifies the first argument to be a pointer to a function returning `double` and accepting unspecified arguments.  This prevents GCC from emitting warnings about mismatched types for the calls to that function in `main()`.

However, function `aux()`'s *definition* gives a more specific type for its first parameter, one that is incompatible with the actual arguments you are passing.  Calling those functions via the pointer has **undefined semantics**.  Pretty much anything could happen, including that the behavior appears to be what you wanted.  You cannot rely on anything about that behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Because you specified prototype of `aux()` before main and `function` doesn't have any specified argument types. Learn the difference:

```
void f();   /* Accepts any number of arguments thanks to K&R C */
void g(void); /* No arguments accepted */
void h(int); /* Only one integer argument accepted */
```

If you declare `aux()` prototype as:

```
void aux(double (*function)(double), double n, double x);
```

GCC starts complaining.

Answer (score 5):

An empty pair of parentheses `()` tells the C compiler that the function may be called with *any* number of parameters, but that the function itself has a specific number of parameters for its prototype. So if using it with a function pointer and the number and respective types of passed parameters match prototype of the pointed-to-function everything will work. If you starve the parameter list or use differently typed values though… well that's undefined behavior.